# Custom URI regular expression

Tags: regex, wordpress, memberpress

I would like to restrict access to my site using a custom URI regular expression.

I would like to allow access for such URIs:

```
https://example.com/item/page/2/?wpv_view_count=258
https://example.com/item/page/3/?wpv_view_count=258
```

and restrict content for such URIs:

```
https://example.com/item/snv00001-indice-di-documenti/
https://example.com/item/sa00068-libro/
https://example.com/item/aud00068-audio/
```

I need to provide the restrict content URI regex

Comment: I added more examples. I need to restrict for /item/snv etc..not for pages

Comment: I am using memberpress on wordpress to restrict content to subscribers. Some pages ex: /snv00001-indice-di-documenti/ should not be available if not subscribed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info in the question you want to match everything *except* requests which start with `/item/page/` so:

```
/item/(?!page/).+
```

That is:

```
/item/  # literal string
(?!     # Begin negative lookahead
  page/ # literal string
)       # End negative lookahead
.+      # 1 or more characters
```

A [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a zero-length match - so the next bit of the regex `.+` continues right after `/item/`.

Here's a demonstration: https://regex101.com/r/8T2ytg/1